# SQL: Setting trigger to limit inserts

Tags: sql, sql-server

This example is a video rental store with entities `Customer`, `Plan`, and `Rental`. Each customer has a plan, and each plan has a maximum number of rentals. I am trying to enforce the constraint on the maximum number of video rentals. I am using SQL Server 2012.

Here is my attempt at creating a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER maxMovies
ON Rental 
FOR INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  IF (0 > (SELECT count(*) 
           FROM (SELECT count(*) as total 
                 FROM Inserted i, rental r 
                 WHERE i.customerID = r.customerID) as t, Inserted i, Rental r 
           WHERE t.total > r.max_movies AND i.customerID = r.customerID) )
  BEGIN
    RAISEERROR("maximum rentals surpassed.")
    ROLLBACK TRAN    
  END
END

-- (rest of query)
DROP table...
```

However, SQL Server gives me the following errors:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure maxMovies, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near 'RAISEERROR'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure maxMovies, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'DROP'.
```

Any suggestions on how to create this trigger?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: No, the question is pretty clear. He's getting an error message, it is due to a typo. Question clear, answer clear, all fine and dandy :-)

Comment: This problem is very obvious when using a Syntax highlighter, even the Stack Overflow syntax hilighter!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `RAISERROR` not `RAISEERROR` - a simple typo. And of course, as Trinimon spotted correctly, strings need to be quoted in single quotes, not double quotes.

```
RAISERROR('maximum rentals surpassed.')
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes instead of quotation marks ...

```
RAISERROR('maximum rentals surpassed.');
```

remove one `E` and add a colon `;`.

Comment: Not just that. There is no `RAISEERROR` function in SQL Server, only `RAISERROR`.

Comment: It should be noted that the colon is not really required ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgI_Rental_VerifyMaxMovies 
ON  dbo.Rental 
FOR INSERT /*, UPDATE*/ -- -- You should also check this limit in the case of UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF /*UPDATE(CustomerID) AND*/ EXISTS ( -- Uncomment in the case of FOR , UPDATE
        SELECT  * 
        FROM    dbo.[Plan] p INNER JOIN dbo.Rental r ON r.CustomerID = p.CustomerID -- Assumption: "Each customer has a plan"
        WHERE   EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted i WHERE i.CustomerID = p.CustomerId)
        GROUP BY p.CustomerID, p.MaxMovies
        HAVING  p.MaxMovies > COUNT(*)
    )
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN;
        RAISERROR('maximum rentals surpassed.', 16, 1);    
    END
END
```